# Exception: CmisConnectionException Cannot access https:\XXXX/CMISWS-Service.wsdl": in CMIS apache chemistry workbench

Tags: cmis-workbench

Java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching , found Cause: SSLHandshakeException java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
I am getting above mentioned error in CMIS apache chemistry workbench when trying to Login even after adding self signed certificate to the jre/lib folder

Comment: Have you checked if the hostname in the URL of the WSDL file and the hostnames in URLs in the WSDL file (there should be 9 URLs) match your certificate?

Comment: Yes whenever i import the same wsdl using soap it is working fine

Comment: I wanted to know how it can be done using workbench

Comment: It's just a SOAP client based on Apache CXF. Maybe your certificate import didn't work correctly.

Comment: You can also try setting the parameter -Dcmis.workbench.acceptSelfSignedCertificates=true in your workbench.bat.

Comment: Yes i have set the Dcmis.workbench.acceptSelfSignedCertificates=true in workbench.bat file I am still facing the same issue as you have told it might be because of certificates, i am yet to figure out the reason